# I dont know if I am being attacked/hacked

Tags: attacks

TCP- or UDP-based Port Scan  Count: 5313
This is what comes up in the firewall "local log". 
The source is from 209.18.47.61

Comment: According to DNS that looks like it's a time warner server,  are they your provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First because your router detected these it means it stopped them from getting to any machine in your network. It wouldn't really matter if it detected it or not because port scans can not get past the NAT function of the router anyway just because it is stupid.

Hard to say what your problem is but do not get mislead messages like this. It is highly unlikely this tiny amount of traffic has any impact. There is nothing you can do about it anyway.

Hoped this helped.